# Using IF ELSE statement based on Count to execute different Insert statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

While I am searching through my database, I run an INSERT statement if I find that a particular item does not exist, and I run a different INSERT statement if I find one or more of this item.

I am not entirely sure how to use the IF ELSE expressions.

What I have so far is a statement that will count the number of times the target data appears; it will print TRUE if it is greater than 0, if not, it will print FALSE. I can't find any examples to help me understand how I can use this to run two different INSERT statements.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
(
  SELECT [Some Column], COUNT(*) TotalCount
  FROM INCIDENTS
  WHERE [Some Column] = 'Target Data'
  GROUP BY [Some Column]
)
```

Comment: how different are the insert statements that you need to run?

Comment: I'm assuming he is using `SQL Server` because of the brackets used in the query.

Comment: OK, thanks for the quick response. The Database is MSSQLSERVER 2008 R2

Comment: You might need to look at [**`EXISTS`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), it might be helpful in your case.

Comment: do you only need to filter results that have count more than 0 ?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Depending on your needs, here are a couple of ways:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'SOME VALUE')
    --INSERT SOMETHING
ELSE
    --INSERT SOMETHING ELSE
```

Or a bit longer

```
DECLARE @retVal int

SELECT @retVal = COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN = 'Some Value'

IF (@retVal > 0)
BEGIN
    --INSERT SOMETHING
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --INSERT SOMETHING ELSE
END
```

Comment: thank you so much! this is exactly what I am looking for! a really simple and elegant solution!

Comment: sorry guys, am I right, that both solutions can be ran only in the procedure, not plain dml (like insert or similar)?

Answer (score 17):

Simply use the following:

```
IF((SELECT count(*) FROM table)=0)
BEGIN

....

END
```

Answer (score 12):

As long as you need to find it based on Count just more than 0, it is better to use EXISTS like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INCIDENTS  WHERE [Some Column] = 'Target Data')
BEGIN
    -- TRUE Procedure
END
ELSE BEGIN
    -- FALSE Procedure
END
```

Answer (score 5):

IF exists

```
IF exists (select * from table_1 where col1 = 'value')
BEGIN
    -- one or more
    insert into table_1 (col1) values ('valueB')
END
ELSE
    -- zero
    insert into table_1 (col1) values ('value')
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very clear what you mean by

> `"I cant find any examples to help me understand how I can use this to
>   run 2 different statements:"`

. Is it using `CASE` like a `SWITCH` you are after?

```
select case when totalCount >= 0 and totalCount < 11 then '0-10'
            when tatalCount > 10 and totalCount < 101 then '10-100'
            else '>100' end as newColumn
from (
  SELECT [Some Column], COUNT(*) TotalCount
  FROM INCIDENTS
  WHERE [Some Column] = 'Target Data'
  GROUP BY [Some Column]
) A
```

Answer (score 1):

one obvious solution is to run 2 separate queries, first select all items that have count=1 and run your insert, then select the items with count>1 and run the second insert.

as a second step if the two inserts are similar you can probably combine them into one query.

another possibility is to use a cursor to loop thru your recordset and do whatever logic you need for each line.

Comment: thanks very much for your input, but 2 separate queries would not suit in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many ways to code this, but here is one possible way.  I'm assuming MS SQL

We'll start by getting row count (Another [Quick Example](http://mssql101.blogspot.com/2010/08/mssql-select-value-into-variable.html)) and then do if/else

```
-- Let's get our row count and assign it to a var that will be used
--    in our if stmt 
DECLARE @HasExistingRows int -- I'm assuming it can fit into an int
SELECT @HasExistingRows = Count(*) 
   ELSE 0 -- false
FROM
   INCIDENTS
WHERE {Your Criteria}
GROUP BY {Required Grouping}
```

Now we can do the If / Else Logic  [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx)

```
-- IF / Else / Begin / END Syntax
IF @HasExistingRows = 0 -- No Existing Rows
   BEGIN
      {Insert Logic for No Existing Rows}
   END
ELSE -- existing rows are found
   BEGIN
      {Insert logic for existing rows}
   END
```

Another faster way (inspired by Mahmoud Gamal's comment):

Forget the whole variable creation / assignment - look up "EXISTS" - [MSDN Docs 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx).

```
IF EXISTS ({SELECT Query})
   BEGIN
      {INSERT Version 1}
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
      {INSERT version 2}
   END
```

Comment: Mahmoud Gamal brings up another great (better) way in his comment: If Exists - that way you are not having to create a variable for existing rows, you can work it right into your IF stmt.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in SQL Server, your syntax is correct; however, you need to reference the COUNT(*) as the Total Count from your nested query.  This should give you what you need:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TotalCount >0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END FROM
(
  SELECT [Some Column], COUNT(*) TotalCount
  FROM INCIDENTS
  WHERE [Some Column] = 'Target Data'
  GROUP BY [Some Column]
) DerivedTable
```

Using this, you could assign TotalCount to a variable and then use an IF ELSE statement to execute your INSERT statements:

```
DECLARE @TotalCount int
SELECT @TotalCount = TotalCount FROM
(
  SELECT [Some Column], COUNT(*) TotalCount
  FROM INCIDENTS
  WHERE [Some Column] = 'Target Data'
  GROUP BY [Some Column]
) DerivedTable
IF @TotalCount > 0
    -- INSERT STATEMENT 1 GOES HERE
ELSE
    -- INSERT STATEMENT 2 GOES HERE
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, Im not entirely sure what you mean by "reference the COUNT(*) as the Total Count from your nested query" this does not parse correctly

Comment: You have a nested query that selects COUNT(*) and assigns it the column TotalCount.  That is a derived table.  Check out my last update and see if that works for you.