# SQL SELECT statement within an IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, if-statement, count

I have a trigger in SQL Server that needs to check on an update the number of rows with a value between a certain amount and do something accordingly. My current code is something like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(id) as NumberOfRows
          FROM database
          WHERE id = 3 AND value <= 20 and value > 2
          GROUP BY id
          HAVING COUNT(id) > 18)
    -- if true, do something
```

From what I can tell, the select statement should find the number of rows with a value between 2 and 20 and if there are more than 18 rows, the `EXISTS` function should return 1 and the query will execute the code within the IF statement.

However, what is happening is that it is always executing the code within the IF statement regardless of the number of rows with a value between 2 and 20.

Any ideas on why this might be? I can post more complete code if it might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL using IF ELSE statement based on count to execute different insert statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072140/sql-using-if-else-statement-based-on-count-to-execute-different-insert-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the `Exists` function is checking the result of the sub-query for `existing` - are there any rows or not. And, as you return the `COUNT`, it'll never be not-existing - `COUNT` returns `0` if there are no rows presented in database.

Try to store the resulting count in a local variable, like in this question:

[Using IF ELSE statement based on Count to execute different Insert statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072140/sql-using-if-else-statement-based-on-count-to-execute-different-insert-statement)

> ```
> DECLARE @retVal int
>
> SELECT @retVal = COUNT(*) 
> FROM TABLE
> WHERE COLUMN = 'Some Value'
>
> IF (@retVal > 0)
> BEGIN
>     --INSERT SOMETHING
> END
> ELSE
> BEGIN
>     --INSERT SOMETHING ELSE
> END
> ```

Comment: This is wrong. EXISTS looks for the presence of **rows**, it doesn't matter if they only consist of NULLs or not. The suggested solution will work but the problem is not NULLs or absence of NULLs.

Comment: Sorry but still wrong. COUNT is just a scalar value. The issue is not the value returned by COUNT. In fact, EXISTS ignores *values*, what matters is *rows*. The subquery has a HAVING clause. That means that the output *can* be empty. (It will be empty if no group matches the HAVING condition.) As I said in my answer, the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like so (single line):

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE ....)>18) BEGIN
...do something
```

You can even do between in a single line

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE ....)between 2 and 20) BEGIN
...do something
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is looking for matches in the entire table. It does not limit the results only to those that are related to the rows affected by the update. Therefore, if the table already has rows matching your condition, the condition will be true on any update that affects *other* rows.

In order to count only the relevant rows, you should either join the `database` table to the `inserted` pseudo-table or use *just* the `inserted` table (there is not enough information in your question to be sure which is better).