# MYSQL query update or insert in PHP using if else

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

```
$getCoins = $this->code = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE coins SET name = ? WHERE id_name = ? IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT INTO coins (id_name) VALUES (?)");

for ($i=0; $i < count($coins) ; $i++) { 

    $id_name = $coins[$i]["id"];
    $name = $coins[$i]["name"];


    $getCoins = $this->code->bind_param('sss', $name, $id_name, $id_name);
    $getCoins = $this->code->execute();
    $getCoins = $this->code->store_result();

}
```

Script return me error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
>   boolean ...

The problem is with `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0` I tryied using IF ELSEl

```
IF(SELECT COUNT(id_name) FROM coins WHERE id_name = 'bitcoin')
    UPDATE coins SET name = 'xxx2' WHERE id_name = 'bitcoin'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO coins (name) VALUES ('new_coins')
END IF
```

but hear is error:

> **#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok 'UPDATE coins SET name = 'xxx2' WHERE id_name = 'bitcoin' ELSE INSERT INTO coi' w linii 2**

I using this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14072357/6678345)

Comment: delimit your statements with ';' and seems odd if you put all your query in one call.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Like this: `UPDATE coins SET name = 'xxx2' WHERE id_name = 'bitcoin'; IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0; INSERT INTO coins (name) VALUES ('new_coins');` I have error: #1193 - Unknown system variable 'ROWCOUNT'

Comment: @michal @@ROWCOUNT doesn't exist in MySQL. It's a SQL Server construct.

Comment: but normally you don't do this kind of coding

Comment: @flip Yes, you're right, but why dont work second solution, when I use `If` and `else`

Comment: @michal You can only use the IF ELSE construct inside of a Stored Procedure or Trigger. If you don't want to put the logic in PHP, then you should look at creating a stored procedure to perform the logic and use PHP to call the stored procedure.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: Why don't you use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option to `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO coins (id_name, name)
VALUES (?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name)
```

If `id_name` already exists, the `name` column will be updated.