# IF Condition Perform Query, Else Perform Other Query Base on Count to Execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, select, count

I want to execute different queries using `IF` and `ELSE` condition...

```
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM dcdetail AS d
           LEFT JOIN finalbilldetail AS f ON d.itemid = f.itemid
           WHERE ISNULL(d.itemcolorid, '') = ISNULL(f.itemcolorid,'')
           AND f.itemid IS NULL
           AND  d.id = 12) > 0 THEN
    SELECT dm.ID
          ,dm.Status
          ,dm.EntryDate
          ,dm.EntryTime
          ,ci.cusid
          ,ci.cusname
          ,ci.cuscontact
    FROM DcMaster AS dm
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RegCustomerInfo AS ci ON dm.customerID = ci.CusID
    WHERE dm.customerid = 8

ELSE 
    (Other Query)
END
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14072357/1073631

Comment: Why do you ask about "if and else", but your sample code uses "case when"?   Why don't you just use `IF` and `ELSE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server `CASE` cannot be used for control flow. Use `IF` instead.

```
IF (SELECT count(*)
           ...) > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT ...
END;
```