# Prevent SQL Job from running if target table is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, scripting

I have an SQL Job which takes two values out of a table and merges them together. 
After the merge, these two values are deleted.

If the table is empty, the Job produces Error-Messages.
How can i prevent this?

Kind regards

Comment: Table empty (no rows) or not created? In any case you can do this validation easily with SQL. For the first case you can use `IF EXISTS ()` for the second you can check against `sys.tables` (for example) to check if table exists.

Comment: Have a look at this question it seems very similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072140/using-if-else-statement-based-on-count-to-execute-different-insert-statements

Comment: @EzLo The table is created but empty.
So i will try it with the IF EXISTS(). Tank you

Comment: @Eponyme Web
I will have  a look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would add a condition to check for an empty table:

```
if exists (select 1 from t)
begin
     -- the merge code or procedure call here
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I'm new to SQL so i didn't figure that out.